# C# How to serialize and deserialize a Dictionary<string,List<string>>?

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

I am developing an app made in Unity and I have a ConfigSave class. Among other variables, it has a dictionary `public Dictionary<string, List<string>> outfits = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();`.
I want to save it like so: `["character A": ["outfit A", "outfit B", "outfit C"], "character B": ["outfit D", "outfit E", "outfit F"]]` (I'm not sure if thats how it would look like).
Anyways, the way I'm saving and loading json files is like this:

```
ConfigSave config;

public void SaveConfig()
{
    config.outfits.Add("test", new List<string> { "test 1", "test 2", "test 3" }); //debug test entry
    string saveData = JsonUtility.ToJson(config);
    string filePath = Application.dataPath + $"/Saves/Config.json";
    string dataPath = Application.dataPath + "/Saves";
    if (!Directory.Exists(dataPath))
        Directory.CreateDirectory(dataPath);

    File.WriteAllText(filePath, saveData);
}

private void LoadConfig(string file)
{
    string jsonContents = File.ReadAllText(file);
    config = JsonUtility.FromJson<ConfigSave>(jsonContents);
}
```

It load and saves other types of variables just fine (string, int, float, bool, list<string>, float[]) but its not saving the dictionary. I dont see it in the resulting .json file.

I tried this code and it prints just like expected. But I guess it's because its not the same Json converter? I'm not very familiar with json, so I'm kinda lost.

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(config.outfits);
Debug.Log(json);
```

prints: `{"test":["test 1","test 2","test 3"]}`

All I found after a bit searching (and even asking chat gpt) got me answers that weren't too suitable for my case. It was either creating a single json file for my dictionary, or you needed to create a whole new class to serialize it.

Comment: Your proposed serialization format isn't valid JSON. An array in JSON doesn't contain key/value pairs - it just contains elements. The serialization format you're seeing in your test looks correct to me, so it looks like JsonConvert should work...

Comment: [`JsonUtility` doesn't support Dictionary at all](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Serialization.html#SerializationRules) ... use something else like [`Newtonsoft Json.NET`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.nuget.newtonsoft-json@2.0/manual/index.html) for instance

Comment: And yeah as @JonSkeet mentions the expected format would rather be somewhat like e.g. `"yourDictionaryField" : { "character A": ["outfit A", "outfit B", "outfit C"] ,  "character B": ["outfit D", "outfit E", "outfit F"]}`

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer, just needed to change the utility I' using. Changing it from JsonUtility to JsonConvert.

`string saveData = JsonUtility.ToJson(config);`
to:
`string saveData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(config);`

`config = JsonUtility.FromJson<ConfigSave>(jsonContents);`
to:
`config = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ConfigSave>(jsonContents);`

I figured it out 5 minutes after posting this haha